# 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated in Swift 5

Tags: ios, deprecated, swift5

I was using following block of code and it works fine. with swift 5, I'm getting following deprecated warning:

> 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use
>   `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws
>   -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

```
data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (dataBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
            _ = CCRandomGenerateBytes!(dataBytes, size)
 }
```

How to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt8.self) }
```

You can also generate random UInt8 using :

```
UInt8.random(in: .min ... .max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr) in
        if let rawPtr = ptr.baseAddress {
            let _ = CCRandomGenerateBytes(rawPtr, size)
        }
    }
```